# Has comma been used to separate an interrupter or to separate a prepositional phrase in this sentence?

Tags: commas

It had been tough, but now he was here, in front of the famous iron pillar.

Prepositional - in front of the famous iron pillar
Interrupter - but now he was here

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your idea of an 'interrupter' is, but in the totally acceptable sentence

- *It had been tough, but now he was here, in front of the famous iron pillar.*

[but now he was here] is *not* a parenthetical. 'It had been tough in front of the famous iron pillar.' changes the sense: the intervening words may not be omitted without changing meaning. The complication is that there are two commas which look as though they could be offsetting a parenthetical. They're not. In fact, I'd prefer a weightier separator after 'tough':

- *It had been tough ... but now he was here, in front of the famous iron pillar.*

A dash or full stop would also be a reasonable choice.

The function of the second comma is to separate complements (in this case, both locatives). It is optional, but its inclusion or omission gives slightly different emphases.

- *It had been tough ... but now he was here, in front of the famous iron pillar.* =
- *It had been tough ... but now he was [here] [in front of the famous iron pillar].*

whereas

- *It had been tough ... but now he was here in front of the famous iron pillar.* =
- *It had been tough ... but now he was [here in front of the famous iron pillar].*

Dramatic pause with focusing in on the famous iron pillar, or smooth running prose. The writer's choice.